# How to hide an element using only js code (and css)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In an existing code, I have an html page which contains some variables that exist in some java classes. What I want to do is **to hide some variables if there are not defined (no value at all) and show the others** like in a normal way.

Here is a portion of the html code :

```
<li id="variable1" class="hide-me-if-blank">
<span class="title-libelle">test1 : </span>
<span class="value-libelle"></span>
</li>
<li id="variable2">
<span class="title-libelle">Description: </span>
<span class="value-libelle"></span>
</li>
```

So, as you can see, the key here is that they created their own css class to hide or show elements. And here is the function (in a .js file) that manages that :

```
/**
*
*   Hide a field if it's null
*
*/
hideIfNull = function(parent, key, val){
    if (undefined != val && !(val instanceof Object )
            && (null == val || 'null' == val || '' == val || !val.trim())) {
        var obj = parent.find("li#" + key);
        var hide = obj.hasClass("hide-me-if-blanc");
        if (hide) {
            obj.addClass('hide');
        }
    } else {
        var obj = parent.find("li#" + key);
        var hide = obj.hasClass("hide-me-if-blanc");
        if (hide) {
            obj.removeClass('hide');
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is that this code is not working if the variable is **not defined yet**. I saw here three cases :
- When the variable has a value => it displays the variable and the value (normal case).
- When the variable is just initialized with no values => it doesn't show anything and it's EXACTLY what I want to have for my third case.
- When the variable is not created yet => it displays the line : "test1 : - " which is completely useless...

So, how can you help me to hide a variable in that case using only js code ? (without additional framework like angular...) Or if you have another solution?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: js only, no framework... Is that jQuery? OK jQ is a JS library but just asking...

Comment: If possible, I want to do it with the "native js", I mean with no additional framework or library :)

Comment: why don't you want jquery? you have jquery in the code you posted.

Comment: Am I missing something?  There's no jQuery in OPs code.

Comment: @Phix I could be wrong, looks like they're passing jquery objects and using jquery functions ($.find(), $.hasClass(), $.removeClass(), etc)

Comment: Err.. I don't see $.hasClass anywhere in the post.  Theres obj.hasClass perhaps

Comment: @Phix they only included a function and not how they're calling it. Here's an example - there are no `$`'s in the function, but it's all jquery, I'm using `$.hasClass(), $.addClass()` - jquery functions. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmZrZd

Comment: Having functions that coincide with jQuery function names doesn't imply it's included. At this point I'm confused and tired, so I bid this thread adieu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery:

```
$("#test1").css("display", "none");
$("#test").css("display", "block");
```

You can use Javascript

```
document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("test1").style.display = "block";
```

This works for every html that uses id, class, name.

```js
$( "#test1" ).click(function() {
  $("#test1").css("display", "none");
  $("#test").css("display", "block");
});
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", displaytest1);
function displaytest1(){
 document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("test1").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#test{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="test">
Press on me test
</div>
<div id ="test1">
Press on me test1
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function hide(x) {
  if (x.getAttribute('class') == null) {
    if (x.innerHTML == "") {
      x.setAttribute('class', 'hide');
    } else {
      x.setAttribute('class', 'show');
    }
  } else {
    if (x.innerHTML != "") {
      var origClass = x.getAttribute('class');
      newClass = origClass.replace("hide", "");
      x.setAttribute('class', newClass);
      var origClass = x.getAttribute('class');
      newClass = origClass.replace("show", "");
      x.setAttribute('class', newClass);
      if (newClass == "") {
        x.setAttribute('class', 'show');
      } else {
        x.setAttribute('class', newClass+' show');
      }
   } else {
     var origClass = x.getAttribute('class');
      newClass = origClass.replace("hide", "");
      x.setAttribute('class', newClass);
      var origClass = x.getAttribute('class');
      newClass = origClass.replace("show", "");
      x.setAttribute('class', newClass);
      if (newClass == "") {
        x.setAttribute('class', 'hide');
      } else {
        x.setAttribute('class', newClass+' hide');
      }
   }
  }
}

liArr = document.body.children[0].children;
for (var i=0;i<liArr.length;i++) {
  hide(liArr[i]);
}
```

```css
.show { visibility:visible; }
.hide { visibility:hidden; }
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>Something</li>
 <li></li>
 <li>Something Else</li>
</ul>
```

**If you want this as an object:**

```js
emptyFinder = function(htmlObj, key, val) {
  this.htmlObj = htmlObj;
  this.key = key;
  this.val = val;
}

emptyFinder.prototype.hide = function(childObj) {
  var x = childObj;
  if (x.getAttribute('class') == null) {
    if (x.innerHTML == this.val) {
      x.setAttribute('class', 'hide');
    } else {
      x.setAttribute('class', 'show');
    }
  } else {
    if (x.innerHTML != this.val) {
        var origClass = x.getAttribute('class');
        newClass = origClass.replace("hide", "");
        x.setAttribute('class', newClass);
        var origClass = x.getAttribute('class');
        newClass = origClass.replace("show", "");
        x.setAttribute('class', newClass);
        if (newClass == "") {
          x.setAttribute('class', 'show');
        } else {
          x.setAttribute('class', newClass+' show');
        }
   } else {
     var origClass = x.getAttribute('class');
        newClass = origClass.replace("hide", "");
        x.setAttribute('class', newClass);
        var origClass = x.getAttribute('class');
        newClass = origClass.replace("show", "");
        x.setAttribute('class', newClass);
        if (newClass == "") {
          x.setAttribute('class', 'hide');
        } else {
          x.setAttribute('class', newClass+' hide');
        }
   }
  }
}

emptyFinder.prototype.doHide = function() {
  var xArr = this.htmlObj.children;
  for (var i=0;i<xArr.length;i++) {
    if(xArr[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == this.key.toLowerCase()) {
      this.hide(xArr[i]);
    }
  }
}

ul = document.body.children[0];
ef1 = new emptyFinder(ul, "li", "");
ef1.doHide();
```

```css
.show { visibility:visible; }
.hide { visibility:hidden; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Somthing</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li>Another</li>
  <li></li>
  <li>Yet Another</li>
  <div>Test 1</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>Test 2</div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here. just check if (val). i just changed the second line

```
hideIfNull = function(parent, key, val){
    if (val) {
       var obj = parent.find("li#" + key);
       var hide = obj.hasClass("hide-me-if-blanc");
       if (hide) {
           obj.addClass('hide');
       }
   } else {
       var obj = parent.find("li#" + key);
       var hide = obj.hasClass("hide-me-if-blanc");
       if (hide) {
          obj.removeClass('hide');
      }
   }
};
```